# Mysql + Python (Guardar Login em Variavel Para fazer Conexão)

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, python-2.7

import os
import getpass
import mysql.connector

class AcessDataBase():

`UserName = ""
PassWard = ""
DataBase = ""

def LoginDB(self):

    self.UserName = input("Username: ")

    os.system("cls")

    self.PassWard = getpass.getpass("Passward")

    os.system("cls")

    self.DataBase = input("DataBase:")

    self.ConectDB() 

def ConectDB(self):

    os.system("cls")

    conexao = mysql.connector.connect(user = self.Username, password = self.Passward,
                                      host = "localhost",   database = self.DataBase )

    os.system("pause")

Sistema = AcessDataBase()

Sistema.LoginDB()`

como posso armazenar as informações nome, senha e o nome da database dentro de uma variável e depois usar a variável para acessar o banco de dados? Tentei Utilizar o Programa acima mas da erro....

Comment: Atenção á indentação das variáveis

Comment: Creio que o seu problema está em `host = "localhost"`. Tente colocar o endereço diretamente, algo como `host = "127.0.0.1"`

Comment: Ja Tentei fazer isso tambem nao da....

Comment: So Funciona quando faço isso: (user = "root" , password = "",
                                      host = "localhost",   database = "nome..." )

Answer (score -1):

O primeiro que achei no seu código é este

```
Sistema.LoginDB()
```

Essa sintaxe puxa uma variável que não existe na classe AcessDataBase
Até onde eu pude ver (Eu também sou bem iniciante) foi que suas funções não estavam acessando as variáveis da classe pública e por isso não estavam alterando nem salvando nada.
Minha dica é que estude mais exemplos que utilizem classes, funções e variáveis entre si.

```
import os
import getpass
import mysql.connector

class AcessDataBase():

    UserName = ""
    PassWard = ""
    DataBase = ""
    conexao = ""


def LoginDB():
    #utilizando o sistema.(variavel) a função estará alterando ou visualizando as
    #Variaveis da classe
    sistema.UserName = input("Username")

    os.system("cls")

    sistema.PassWard = getpass.getpass("Passward")

    os.system("cls")

    sistema.DataBase = input("Database")

    os.system("cls")

def ConectDB():

    os.system("cls")

    sistema.conexao = mysql.connector.connect(user=sistema.UserName, password=sistema.PassWard,
                                              host="localhost", database=sistema.DataBase)

    os.system("pause")

sistema=AcessDataBase()

LoginDB()

ConectDB()
```